# netty memory leak

Tags: java, memory, netty, memory-leaks

```
Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer(); 
        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new PortNettyFactory(timer,port));
        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

I use netty display memory leak in Jprofiler.  please suggest to me, thanks!!!

Comment: To get useful replies please post more details on the memory leak. Do you get OutOfMemoryError(s)? If yes do you know what events trigger this error? Have you tried -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag and analysed the heap dump? Suggest you to reduce your JVM heap size so reproducing it is easier and heap dump analysis is easier and quicker.

Comment: DownstreamMessageEvent
DefaultChannelFutrue two class leak

Comment: What you mean with leak ? It is correct that a bind will produce a DefaultChannelFuture and a DownstreamMessageEvent. So I don't see a problem here..